# How to add an arrow into the left of Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I add an arrow like the picture below:

[image: this is a picture with an arrow]

If I cannot add it into the `Grid`, is it possible to add it into the first `StackPanel`?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"  MinWidth="400"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"  MinWidth="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

This is a picture without an arrow:

[image: this is a picture without an arrow]

Comment: You should use Adorner.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it is difficult to understand your question. Your two pictures do not appear to be related to each other, and it's not clear at all what element the arrow is to be associated with or why. Please show a good code example that includes data, view model, XAML, etc., all in a _complete_ form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use a `Path` for design:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"  MinWidth="400"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"  MinWidth="300"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Path Data="M 0 0 L 0 10 L 5 5" Margin="0,0,-93,0"
                  StrokeThickness="0"
                  Stroke="Orange"
                  Fill="Orange" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code which shows Arrow(triangle) as adorner. You can also use an image instead of drawing. Search google for "Adorner tutorials WPF" .

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid ... >
  ...
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#FFEEE528">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ArrowAdorner.cs

```
public class ArrowAdorner : Adorner
    {
        private FrameworkElement _adornedElement;
        public ArrowAdorner(FrameworkElement adornedElement)
            : base(adornedElement)
        {
            _adornedElement = adornedElement;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            var height = _adornedElement.ActualHeight;
            var width = _adornedElement.ActualWidth;    


            drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), new Point(width, 0), new Point(width, height));
            drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), new Point(width,0), new Point(width / 2, height / 2));
            drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), new Point(width, height), new Point(width / 2, height / 2));
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.cs

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //attach adorner
            var adornedTextBlock = tb;
            var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(adornedTextBlock);
            adornerLayer.Add(new ArrowAdorner(adornedTextBlock));
        }
```

If you want to add an Image control in Adorner, try following link : 
[Any control in adorner](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/28/wpf-adorners-part-2-ndash-placing-any-control-on-the.aspx).

Comment: thanks.i searched use an image instead of drawing in Adorner.but i can not find in google.could you give a tip for that.thaks again.

Comment: @nainaigu see updated answer for http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/28/wpf-adorners-part-2-ndash-placing-any-control-on-the.aspx